# Pandas - Replace multiple column values with previous column value when condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large dataframe that looks like this:

```
Start       End        Alm_No1 Val_No1  Alm_No2 Val_No2 Alm_No3 Val_No3
1/1/19 0:00 1/2/19 0:00    1       0       2       1       3       0
1/2/19 0:00 1/3/19 0:00    1       0       2       0       3       1
1/3/19 0:00 1/4/19 0:00    1       1       2       0       3       0
1/4/19 0:00 1/5/19 0:00    1       0       2       0       3       1
1/5/19 0:00 1/6/19 0:00    1       1       2       0       3       0
1/6/19 0:00 1/7/19 0:00    1       0       2       1       3       1
1/7/19 0:00 1/8/19 0:00    4       0       5       1       6       0
1/8/19 0:00 1/9/19 0:00    4       0       5       1       6       1
1/9/19 0:00 1/10/19 0:00   4       1       5       1       6       0
```

I want to update all values in columns "Val" with the number from the associated "Alm" column if the value is 1 so that I can get rid of the "Alm" columns.

The outcome would look like this:

```
Start           End     Alm_No1  Val_No1 Alm_No2 Val_No2  Alm_No3 Val_No3
1/1/19 0:00 1/2/19 0:00    1       0       2       2       3       0
1/2/19 0:00 1/3/19 0:00    1       0       2       0       3       3
1/3/19 0:00 1/4/19 0:00    1       1       2       0       3       0
1/4/19 0:00 1/5/19 0:00    1       0       2       0       3       3
1/5/19 0:00 1/6/19 0:00    1       1       2       0       3       0
1/6/19 0:00 1/7/19 0:00    1       0       2       2       3       3
1/7/19 0:00 1/8/19 0:00    4       0       5       5       6       0
1/8/19 0:00 1/9/19 0:00    4       0       5       5       6       6
1/9/19 0:00 1/10/19 0:00   4       4       5       5       6       0
```

I have created the list of columns which value should be changed:

```
val_col = df.columns.tolist()
val_list=[]
for i in range(0, len(val_col)) : 
    if val_col[i].startswith('Val'): 
        val_list.append(i)
```

then I tried creating a while look to iterate over the columns:

```
for x in val_list: 
    i = 0 
    while i < len(df): 
        if df.iloc[i, x] == 1: 
            df.iloc[i, x] = df.iloc[i, x-1] 
            i+=1
```

It takes forever too load and I have a hard time finding something that works with lambda or apply. Any hint? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never loop over the rows of a dataframe. You should set columns all in one operation.

```
for i in range(1,4): 
    df[f'Val_No{i}'] *= df[f'Alm_No{i}']
```

Comment: Thank you BallpointBen, your solution is even better than mine:
129 ms ± 6.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly answering my own questions just a few minutes later but I think I found something that works:

```
for x in val_list:
    df.loc[df.iloc[:,x]==1,df.columns[x]] = df.iloc[:, x-1]
```

Worked like a charm!

```
234 ms ± 15.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution working for **arbitrary** number of *Alm_No...* /
*Val_No...* columns.

Let's start from a function to be applied to each row:

```
def fn(row):
    for i in range(2, row.size, 2):
        j = i + 1
        if row.iloc[j]:
            row.iloc[j] = row.iloc[i]
    return row
```

Note the construction of the *for* loop. It starts from *2*
(position of `Alm_No1` column), with step *2* (the distance to
`Alm_No2` column).

`j` holds the number of the next column (*Val_No...*).

If the "current" *Val_No* != 0 then substitute here the value
from the "current" *Alm_No*.

After the loop completes the changed row is returned.

So the only thing to do is to apply this function to each row:

```
df.apply(fn, axis=1)
```

My *timeit* measurements indicated that my solution runs a little
(7 %) quicker than yours and about **35 times** quicker than the one
proposed by *BallpointBen*.

Apparently, the usage of f-strings has some share in this (quite significant)
difference.